# How do I get the current controller in a Laravel 5.2 Service Provider boot or register method?

Tags: php, laravel-5, service-provider

I've got a little problem on my hands. I can't manage to get the current controller name from the request in a Service Provider.

I want to dynamically provide a different repository by typehinting the same interface based on the controller I'm currently in.

My current service provider looks something like this, but the request()->route() returns null.

```
private $currentController;

private static $controllerBindings = [
    'FooController' => ['RepositoryInterface' => 'FooRepository'],
];

private static $bindings = [
    'SomeInterface' => 'SomeRepository'
];

public function boot()
{
    $controller = request()->route()->getAction()['controller'];
    $controller = preg_replace('/@[a-zA-Z0-9]+/', '', $controller);

    $this->currentController = $controller;
}


public function register()
{
    if ( array_key_exists($this->currentController, self::$controllerBindings) ) {
        foreach (self::$controllerBindings[$this->currentController] as $interface => $dependency) {
            app()->bind($interface, $dependency);
        }
    }
    else {
        foreach (self::$bindings as $interface => $dependency) {
            app()->bind($interface, $dependency);
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried doing this and it gives: BindingResolutionException in Container.php line 748:
Target [App\Business\Interfaces\RepositoryInterface] is not instantiable while building [App\Http\Controllers\Admin\SettingsController].

```
private static $bindings = [
    'App\Http\Controllers\SettingsController' => [
        'App\Business\Interfaces\RepositoryInterface' => 'App\Business\Admin\Repositories\SettingsRepository',
    ],
];

public function boot()
{

}

public function register()
{
    foreach (self::$bindings as $entity => $binding) {
        if ( is_array($binding) ) {
            $this->bindEntityFromArray($entity, $binding);
        }
        else {
            app()->bind($entity, $binding);
        }
    }
}

private function bindEntityFromArray($entity, array $bindings)
{
    foreach ($bindings as $interface => $dependency) {
        app()->when($entity)->needs($interface)->give($dependency);
    }
}
```

I inject the RepositoryInterface into the Controller's constructor.

Comment: Well, routing happens after service providers finishes bootstrapping. I don't think that this is possible in an easy way.

Comment: I think I'm going to choose a different approach.